# Where are the Interior water valves for my outdoor hose bibs?

Tags: plumbing, valve

I live in a condo in Northeast Ohio.  No basement, small patio with outside hose bibs.  Interior wall has corner gas fireplace.  I and two plumbers have searched everywhere for the interior valves to turn on outside water.  They both found piping inside fireplace [REALLY!!] and no valve.  Nothing found in small utility room.  Behind washer/dryer is a valve for water spout in garage.  This valve should be visible and not hidden.  Condo built in 2002.  ANY IDEAS/SUGGESTIONS - WHERE OH WHERE IS THE VALVE?  THANK YOU!!

Comment: It's possible the builder didn't install any shutoffs. either way, you could always shut off the main water source, and install your own.

Comment: I can't find a way to turn the water on.  I'm not wondering if this is a sign the Frost Free Anti-Siphon unit needs to be replaced??

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely overlooked where you said you wanted to turn the water *on* (I just immediately assumed the opposite).